# While writing inside a cats ear with a sharpy, harm a cat?

Tags: cats, health

Someone wrote inside of my cats ear using a Sharpie marker.

What I suspect: The insides of ears are sensitive areas, and the chemicals inside the Sharpie might cause skin irritation and infection.

Should I be concerned?

Comment: Do you have photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha no don't worry it's all good unless the pen or marker got threw her skin, in that case you should clean the area just like the way you clean your injuries. But if you use an alcohol cleanser it might be better if you clean it with water once it's done it's effect, so the cat won't try to lick it afterwards.